# matlab zplane function: handles of vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm interested in understanding the variety of zeroes that a given function produces with the ultimate goal of identifying the what frequencies are passed in high/low pass filters. My idea is that finding the lowest value zero of a filter will identify the passband for a LPF specifically. I'm attempting to use the `[hz,hp,ht] = zplane(z,p)` function to do so.

The description for that function reads "returns vectors of handles to the zero lines, hz". Could someone help me with what a vector of a handle is and what I do with one to be able to find the various zeros?

For example, a simple 5-point running average filter:
`runavh = (1/5) * ones(1,5)`;

using `zplane(runavh)` gives an acceptable pole/zero plot, but running the `[hz,hp,ht] = zplane(z,p)` function results in hz=175.1075. I don't know what this number represents and how to use it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/get.html) command, you can find out things about the data.

For example, type `G=get(hz)` to get a list of properties of the zero lines. Then the `XData` is given by `G.XData`, i.e. `X=G.XData`.

Alternatively, you can only pull out the data you want

```
X=get(hz,'XData')
```

Hope that helps.